# How to take the backup of full database using mysql?

Tags: mysql

How to take the backup of full database using mysql?

Comment: The qustion is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238898/how-to-take-backup-of-database-in-php/34238942?noredirect=1#comment56221053_34238942

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mysqldump`. Have a look at the reference manual: [4.5.4. mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

> [mysqldump] can be used to dump a database or a collection of databases for backup or transfer to another SQL server (not necessarily a MySQL server). **The dump typically contains SQL statements to create the table, populate it, or both**.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using mysqldump, you can create an Scheduled task or a cron job to automatize the backup process:

mysqldump --opt --host=localhost --user=myUser --password=myPass --result-file=C:\Backups\myBackupFile.sql myDatabase

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to phpMyadmin, try the export function as it's probably the easiest way.