# How to take backup of database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing some projects related to finance and for that i am using mysql database.Can any one suggest me how to take backup of database after each operation?

Comment: A backup after each operation? That would be _very_ uncommon... Usually backups are taken independent of runtime on a time based schedule. So once a night for example. For that you can best use something like `mysqldump` and trigger it by means of a cron job. If however you are looking for a solution to be able to "roll back" each operation performed on that database, then take a look at "transactions" instead and logging.

Comment: Maybe you need a [Data warehouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse).

Comment: If you want to take logs of each transactions you may use [TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Ans updated. try this code and i hope, this will work fine for you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this code, enter host, username, password, database or table name in first line : `backup_tables('localhost','useranme','password','database_or_table_name');`

You will get a file named `db-backup.......` in htdocs.
This works for me. Try This code:

```
<?php

// Enter database name here

backup_tables('localhost','useranme','password','database_or_table_name');

/* backup the db OR just a table */
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{

    $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($name,$link);

    //get all of the tables
    if($tables == '*')
    {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
    }

    //cycle through
    $return = "";
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        $return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                for($j=0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) 
                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                    $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                    if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                    if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                }
                $return.= ");\n";
            }
        }
        $return.="\n\n\n";
    }

    //save file
    $handle = fopen('db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
    fwrite($handle,$return);
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```